# What is the probability that a bivariate Gaussian generates a point beyond a certain line?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-statistical-analysis

**Context:** Consider the problem of identifying the error probability associated with a given classifier.  Assume that the points produced by the two classes, namely A and B, are characterized by bivariate Gaussians. In this context, the classifier may be characterized by a line and the probability of error is related to the probability that a point is beyond that line.

**Question:** Given a line $y=ax+b$, what is the probability that a bivariate Gaussian generates a point beyond that line?

Case 1) In the simplest case, we assume that the bivariate Gaussian is normalized, with mean (0, 0), correlation 0, and variances 1.   We also assume $b=0$. Intuitively, I think in this case the answer is that the sampled point will be in each side of the line with probability 1/2

Case 2a) In this case, we assume that the bivariate Gaussian is normalized, with mean (0, 0), correlation 0, and variances 1.   We assume $b \neq 0$

Case 2b) In this case, we assume that the bivariate Gaussian is general, with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.   We assume $b = 0$

Case 3) Now, we assume that the bivariate Gaussian is general with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. We assume $b \neq 0$

Comment: Well, you know the density and the domain, you have to integrate.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut are there closed form solutions?

Comment: You may use the symmetry of the density to simplify the integral. For instance, rotate the line to make it horizontal for 2a).

Comment: You can always transform to case 2a with $a=0$ and then use $\Phi$ (related to the CDF of a single variable standard normal variable) to get the answer. But there is not a closed form for $\Phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to work all the cases in one shot as follows. First you consider  $(X,Y)=N(\mu_1,\mu_2, \Sigma)$ where $$\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\sigma_1^2&\rho \sigma_1\sigma_2\\\rho \sigma_1\sigma_2&\sigma_2^2\end{array}\right].$$ Next you write$$X=\mu_1+\sigma_1X_1,\ Y=\mu_2+\sigma_2Y_1$$ where $X_1, Y_1 \sim N(0,1)$ with correlation coefficient $\rho.$ Second step you write
$$Y_1=\rho X_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z$$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $X_1.$ Third step: you rewrite the event $Y>aX+b$ under the form
$$X_1\geq \alpha Z+\beta.$$ Fourth step you consider
$$Z_1=\frac{X_1-\alpha Z}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}, z_1=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}$$ and you observe that $Z_1\sim N(0,1)$ and the probability of the event $Y>aX+b$ is $\Pr(Z_1>z_1).$

Comment: $$X_1\geq \alpha Z+\beta.$$ 


Indeed, 

$$Y > a X + b$$

$$\mu_2 + \sigma_2 \left( \rho X_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z \right) > a (\mu_1 + \sigma_1 X_1) + b$$


$$\sigma_2 \rho X_1  > a (\mu_1 + \sigma_1 X_1) + b - \mu_2 - \sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z $$


$$(\sigma_2 \rho -  a \sigma_1) X_1  > a \mu_1   + b - \mu_2 - \sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z $$

Therefore,
$$\beta=\frac{a \mu_1   + b - \mu_2 }{\sigma_2 \rho -  a \sigma_1}$$

$$\alpha=\frac{- \sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}{\sigma_2 \rho -  a \sigma_1} $$

Comment: I guess that the result above holds if $\sigma_2 \rho - a \sigma_1 > 0$. I think that if that is not the case, than we should replace $P(Z_1 > z_1)$ by $P(Z_1 < z_1)$. Are there any other conditions that must be checked for the above result to hold?

@Gérard Letac

Comment: Daniel you are right of course. Thanks for having computed all these constants.

Comment: follow up to generalize to multiple dimensions here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848267/what-is-the-probability-that-a-multivariate-gaussian-generates-a-point-above-a-c